# Datetimepicker doesn't use the given format

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, date, format

I'm currently using the [Date time picker](https://plugins.jquery.com/datetimepicker/) of JQuery, but it's not using the given format. Instead of using that, it uses it's default date format and gives an error in the console: `Uncaught TypeError: F.mask.replace is not a function`. I get this error when I lose focus of the Date time picker.

Something, though, I get another error right after the page loaded: `maximum call stack size exceeded`.

How do I make sure it uses the given format?

If you need any additional information, feel free to ask.

**HTML**

```
<input id="start" value="01-01-2016" />
```

**CSS**

```
$('#start').datetimepicker({
    formatTime: 'H:i',
    formatDate: 'dd-mm-yy',
    defaultDate: '01-01-2016',
    defaultTime: '10:00'
});
```

**Additional information**

[This](https://github.com/xdan/datetimepicker/blob/master/build/jquery.datetimepicker.full.js) is the date time picker code that I use. The error (`Uncaught TypeError: F.mask.replace is not a function`) is on line 1743.

Comment: F.mask.replace is not a function -> the problem is here...

Comment: @Meiko I understand, but how do I make sure it uses the given format?

Comment: I think the code in your question should work. But it is not executed, because the interpreter breaks the execution when the error "is not a function" occurs

Comment: @Meiko Okay, but how do I get it working then?

Comment: I do not know, because I cannot see the code where the error happens...

Comment: @Meiko Here it is: https://gyazo.com/695407b74559fa31de074c2aebb59c1e.png

Comment: hm :) you should put in in your question. maybe all code to reproduce the error, then I'm sure that the glory community is able to help... ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in the master branch. It is [already fixed](https://github.com/xdan/datetimepicker/commit/ef522190fb59c5149dbb7f08405d18cb5d6cd300), but still exists in the concatenated file [jquery.datetimepicker.full.js](https://github.com/xdan/datetimepicker/blob/master/build/jquery.datetimepicker.full.js). If you do not want to use this [release versions](https://github.com/xdan/datetimepicker/releases), you could use the file [jquery.datetimepicker.js](https://github.com/xdan/datetimepicker/blob/master/jquery.datetimepicker.js) and add the required dependencies:

If you use bower, you could add the dependencies from here https://github.com/xdan/datetimepicker/blob/master/bower.json to your own bower.json:

```
"jquery": ">= 1.7.2",
"jquery-mousewheel": ">= 3.1.13",
"php-date-formatter": ">= 1.3.3"
```

or:

```html
<link href="https://rawgit.com/xdan/datetimepicker/master/jquery.datetimepicker.css"  type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/jquery/jquery-mousewheel/master/jquery.mousewheel.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kartik-v/php-date-formatter/master/js/php-date-formatter.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/xdan/datetimepicker/master/jquery.datetimepicker.js"></script>

<input id="start" value="01-01-2016" />
<script>
  $( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#start').datetimepicker({
      formatTime: 'H:i',
      formatDate: 'dd-mm-yy',
      defaultDate: new Date(2016,01,01),
      defaultTime: '10:00'
    });
  });

</script>
```